# How to return values from postgres update using a join

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-update, sql-returning

I'm working with postgres and I want to write a single query that both updates a boolean value and when it's finished shows the updated value plus some additional columns. currently, I'm using the **returning** statement, but some of the columns I would like to display come from a join with another table (actores)

This is my current query:

```
update entradas set vendida=false where ticket_id - 1134 = 101 returning ticket_id-1134 as numero_entrada, vendida, name, fecha;
```

name and fecha are fields in the table actores, so how could I do something resembling:

```
from entradas join actores on entradas.user_id = actores.user_id
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Prefix the table name to the column name, so if you have data with the same column names from table_A and table_B, or even from a named query, you can do:

`table_A.column_name, table_B.column_name, query.column_name` to explicitly reference the columns you want.

For the join, here is the syntax you want to look at:

```
UPDATE mytable
    SET vendida = false
FROM entradas
  JOIN actores ON entradas.user_id = actores.user_id
WHERE (ticket_id - 1134) = 101
RETURNING (,,,)
;
```

Comment: I would still be missing the join part. the columns will not be accessible from say table_B because I never joined them in this query.

Comment: Sorry, I re-read your question now (my browser crashed and the quoted code went blank) - I thought you'd already written the join statement but couldn't refer to the different columns.

Comment: @AnaCruz I edited my answer to give an example of the syntax that I think you're looking for - you might need to modify it slightly, I've probably got a couple typos!

Comment: Why the expression  `ticket_id - 1134 = 101` when ` ticket_id = 1235` is exactly the same?

Comment: The predicate is suspect, but the simplification **does not** produce the *same* result @Belayer